# how to insert array value in indexof in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I want to search `words_array` words in text but when i use `words_array[0]` in index of it shows me `-1` having array word present in text and when i use direct like Death it shows me the index how to make it possible to use array words

```
function check_val()
{
    var words_array=new Array("Death","Kill","Murder");
    var check_text=document.getElementById("text").value;
    var val=words_array[0];
    alert(check_text.indexOf(val.toString()));
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="check_val();" value="check">
```

Comment: Well, `'death' !== 'Death'`. Please give a clear demonstration with specific input values.

Comment: `/Death|Kill|Murder/i.test(ckh_text)`

Comment: Your code works fine. If I enter 'helpDeath' into the input, I see an index of 4 which is correct.

It seems the only issue is the case difference. If you want to ignore capitalisation, then you could try 

`check_text.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase())`

NB: You don't  need the `toString()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Your array element and input value must be in same case.

Try to enter  `Death` it returns 0, or `Kill` returns 1

Comment: Being case-sensitive is true, but still it won't work as he is using `indexOf()` on the string to be searched and not on the array.

Comment: yes i use indexof in string and have to find array words in that

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be as below:

```
function check_val()
{
    var words_array=new Array("Death","Kill","Murder");
    var check_text=document.getElementById("text").value;
    alert(words_array.indexOf(check_text.toString()));
}
```

Also notice that the `indexOf()` is case sensitive, meaning 'Death' and 'death' are not the same and would return index -1

Comment: Also `indexOf()` works on an `array`. By what you have posted, you are using it on the string to be searched

Comment: yes i have a text box and i need to search some words in text box text using array words

Comment: is there any other option to use in place of indexof

Comment: @Sanchit  The OP is asking how to check for the presence of a specific word in an input field. You are telling him how to check the occurrence of the entire input field in an array of values. This is not the same thing at all.

For example  - check whether helpmurder contains any value in the array ['murder','death'] is true. But you are checking whether the array ['murder','death'] contains the value 'helpmurder'.